# android ( trying to use hdpi images for both phones and tabs ) but not working

Tags: android

I am trying to do a splash screen  in android   when  have used (xxxhdpi)  for tabs , but when i am using it in mobile phone the image is just stretching out so please help me out

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of things here. First of all, why do u want to keep only a single copy of the image you are talking about?

Its always better to have the images for all the respective densities, otherwise android will do the downscaling and upscaling on your images. 
If apk size is a concern, you can look into density splits.

Now, back to your issue, it depends on the scaleType of your imageview. You can do something like this (in case you dont care about the dimentions of the image, otherwise you can set scaleType to fitXY):

```
<ImageView
  ...
  android:scaleType="centerCrop"
  ...
</ImageView>
```

Now for loading the image into your imageview, I'll hghly recommend you use Picasso library. 
In your activity, you can do something like this:

```
onCreate(...){
  ...
  Picasso.with(mContext).load(R.drawable.my_splash_image).into(mMyImageView);
  ...
}
```

Let me know if this clears your doubts.

Comment: all the above answer not working properly , wish some some could help me . i am using images of landscape and portrait  of different  densities... so what should i do so that it will work properly

Comment: Not a problem. Lets work with one image for now. We will try to work on my first suggestion later on. Now, do you know how to use Picasso library ? Link is: http://square.github.io/picasso/ 

Just go through it once and then load the image using this library instead of using the android:src attribute of the imageview. Will upload a sample code later in the night today. Try it out and let me know in case u have any doubts.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your image stretching problem try:

```
<ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:scaleType="centerCrop"
           android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

Also I suggest you to read [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 0):

try with this activity as your splash activity.
1.SplashActivity.java

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    Thread timerThread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(3000);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    };
    timerThread.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}}
```

2.make a layout like this
splash.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/splash_image"
android:orientation="vertical">
```

3.make sure that you manifest should launch the app main thread.like bellow
manifest.xml

```
        <activity
        android:name="com.example.brahmaiah.demo_proj_filpkart.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

`hope this will work fine for you.